# Fiber sequence of principal bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, fibration

Let $G$ be a group, either a Lie group or a discrete group. Let a principal $G$-bundle
$$G\to E\to B,$$
then $B=E/G$, the orbit space under action of $G$. Let $BG$ be the classifying space of $G$.

> How to get the following fiber sequence: $$G\simeq \Omega BG\to E\to B\to BG?$$

Answer (score 1):

The classifying space $BG$ has a [universal principal $G$-bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_bundle) $\xi_{u} : EG \to BG$ with the universal property that for any principal $G$-bundle $\xi : E \to B$, there exists a classifying map (unique up to homotopy) $f : B \to BG$ such that $f^* \xi_u = \xi$. In other words there is a pullback diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
E @>>> EG \\
@V{\xi}VV @V{\xi_u}VV \\
B @>{f}>> BG
\end{CD}$$
It follows that $EG$ is contractible, so $E$ is the homotopy pullback $B \times^h_{BG} *$. Thus you get a fiber sequence (I don't know how you defined them but that's probably equivalent to this) $E \to B \to BG$.